# How to resolve HTTPErrosResponse issues in Angular

Tags: angular, http

I have been trying to delete an item from local database with following code. unfortunately not able to delete item but getting 420 error. what could be the issue expert advice please?

[image]

**data.services.ts**

```
deleteDiscipline(id: number, requestBody:any) {
    return this.http.post(this.configService.apiUrl + 'disciplines/' + id + '/delete', requestBody, httpOptions )
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('deleteitem', requestBody))
    );
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
    deleteData($event:any){
    if($event == "delete") {


    this.requestBody = {
         name : { "en" : this.selectedItem.name.en, "de" : this.selectedItem.name.de},
         id : this.selectedId
    }
     this.dataService.deleteDiscipline(this.selectedId, this.requestBody )
      .subscribe( data => {
          this.logger.log("deleted successfully" + data);
          this.notificationService.showNotification('success', '', 'Deleted successfully');
          this.router.navigate(['technicalSettings/disciplines']);
      })
    }
  }
```

**server script**

```
@POST
@Path(ID_PATH + DELETE) 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response delete(@PathParam(ID) final String id) throws Exception {
 ----- code goes here -- 
}
```

Comment: if you are using spring framework, seems like the method is breaking

Comment: This is pure Angular development with version 7 quick start code

Comment: Are you sure that that method is a POST request and not a DELETE request?

Comment: Can you post the code for the local server at '/delete'?

Comment: It is POST method for some data purpose used post method. I have updated the local server script sample.

Answer (score 0):

If your API is expecting delete request, you should use `http.delete` instead of `http.post`.

It'd better to share the API method which you are using for the delete.

Edit:
As you mentioned in the comment that it is a POST API, the error is on the API end as the request is being sent from the Angular end, and it is getting the error from the API. Debug the API to catch the exact error.

Comment: @POST
    @Path(ID_PATH + DELETE)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response delete(@PathParam(ID) final String id) throws Exception { ----- code goes here -- }